# Current Location not showing in the map on Motorola device

Tags: android, google-maps

Im using google maps in my app, the code work fine and show the current location , i dont know why my codes work but only in samsung device , not in motorola... i don't know if i miss some permission for others device ..
 if anyone can give me some help with that .. will be very nice
this  my code

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);      
    getLocationPermission();
    initMap();
}
private void getLocationPermission(){
    String[] permission ={
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
            getDeviceLocation();
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,permission,
                    LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }else{
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                permission,
                LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
private void initMap() {
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync((OnMapReadyCallback) this);
}
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    if (mLocationPermissionsGranted) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);        
    }     
}
private void getDeviceLocation(){
    Log.d("MapsActivity.this", "getDeviceLocation: getting the devices current location");

    mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    try{
        if(mLocationPermissionsGranted){

            final Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
            location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Log.d("MapsActivity.this", "onComplete: found location!");
                        Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();

                        moveCamera(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()),
                                DEFAULT_ZOOM,"My location");

                    }else{
                        Log.d("MapsActivity.this", "onComplete: current location is null");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "unable to get current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }catch (SecurityException e){
        Log.e("MapsActivity.this", "getDeviceLocation: SecurityException: " + e.getMessage() );
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the versions and API level of those 2 devices? And do you get any errors in your logcat?

Comment: the logcat did'nt show me any errors , and the api level oh those devices are (Samsung) 22 and 23 and the motorola device is API 27

Comment: I see, can you please post your app-level build.gradle and manifest?

Comment: i fixed  it @evan i just change the configuration of mode location to the motorola device

Comment: Thanks for your update, glad to hear! :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I just changed the configuration of the device, one of those three must work fine